# Is NFC NDEF supported on Kitkat?

Tags: android, nfc, android-4.4-kitkat, ndef

I am trying to read NFC NDEF Messages using a MobiPrint Device running on KitKat.

I followed the instructions in the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc), but I can't seem to get it to work on Kitkat.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pos">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Pos">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.views.main.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Pos.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
   
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private var adapter: NfcAdapter? = null
    private var pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            Intent(this, javaClass).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        adapter?.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        adapter?.disableForegroundDispatch(this)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)

        val rawMessages = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)
        Log.d("NFC_NDEF_MESSAGES", rawMessages.toString())
        Log.d("NFC_NDEF_ACTION", intent.action.toString())
    }
}
```

**Logcat Messages**

MobiPrint Device with Kitkat:

NFC_NDEF_MESSAGES: `null`
NFC_NDEF_ACTION: `android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED`

S7 Active with Marshmallow:

NFC_NDEF_MESSAGES: `[Landroid.os.Parcelable;@6405e69`
NFC_NDEF_ACTION: `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED`

Is NDEF not supported on Kitkat?

Comment: What is the Tag make and Model?

Comment: Model: MobiPrint, Make: MobiWire

Comment: MobiPrint / MobiWire seems to me to be the Make/Model of the Device trying to do the reading of the NFC Tag not the Make/Model of the NFC Tag which has the NDEF data stored on it you are trying to read from (which is what I'm after)

Comment: The Cards(Tags) are custom made. How can I view the make and model from Android Studio?

Comment: Install and use the "NXP Taginfo" Android App on the S7 Active device and do a full scan of the Tag, it will give you lots of info on the Tag Device

Comment: I kept getting an error with "NXP Taginfo" so I used "NFC Tools" and this is what I got:

Tag type: ISO 14443-3A
NXP MIFARE Classic 1k

Technologies available
Nfca, MifareClassic, Ndef

Serial number
50:1D:6C:C9

ATQA
0x0004

SAK
0x08

Memory Information
1 kBytes: 16 sectors of 4 blocks(16 bytes per block)

Data formart
NXP Mifare Classic

Size
23 / 716 Bytes

Writable
Yes

Can be made Read-Only
Yes

Record 0 - UTF-8 (en): text/plain
0000590810726125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NXP MIFARE Classic series of NFC Cards do not conform to the NFC Forum standards (the specification pre-dates the NFC Standards)

Thus some hardware does not support the NXP MIFARE Classic series of NFC Cards and if you look at the Android docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic

> Implementation of this class on a Android NFC device is optional. If it is not implemented, then MifareClassic will never be enumerated in Tag#getTechList. If it is enumerated, then all MifareClassic I/O operations will be supported, and Ndef#MIFARE_CLASSIC NDEF tags will also be supported. In either case, NfcA will also be enumerated on the tag, because all MIFARE Classic tags are also NfcA.

So support for this type of card is Optional in Android and as it says if it is supported then the higher level NDEF protocol will be support on top of it (but as in your case it is not supported at the MifareClassic level then NDEF won't be supported on top)

This is probably why you are getting the `android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED` message as this comes from the low level `NfcA` which is a low very protocol which MifareClassic has in common with other NFC Specification cards.

Solution to get the MobiPrint Device to read NFC tag is use buy different NFC Tags unfortunately, this is nothing to do with the Android Version (Even some later Android hardware won't read them), I Suggest using an NFC Forum specification type Tag.
A close match is the NXP TAG 216 card (NFC Forum Type 2) or the NXP Desfire (NFC Forum Type 4)

Comment: One does not need any different NFC tags, but only has to format them to NDEF.

Comment: @Martin Zeitler Given that the Tag in question is already formatted and has NDEF data on it (As shown by the successful NDEF reading using the S7 device and the NFC Tools info then your statement about just formatting it cannot be true)

Comment: I installed "NFC Tools" and "NXP Taginfo" on the MobiPrint and I couldn't get NDEF info on both apps. So I'll have to agree with @Andrew

Comment: @francis This logic makes no sense - as the problem is barely KitKat specific.

Comment: Should have said there is also a good paragraph at the top the the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef - "For guaranteed compatibility across all Android devices with NFC, it is recommended to use NFC Forum Types 1-4 in new deployments of NFC tags with NDEF payload. Vendor NDEF formats will not work on all Android devices. " with `MIFARE_CLASSIC` being listed as a Vendor specific format.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it detects it as `TAG_DISCOVERED` (which usually hints for an absent NDEF format). And even when if fails to detect it as `MifareUltralight`, one still can use it as `NfcA`, with the CC at page 3, data-area starts on page 4 (no matter if formatting or reading the format). When the tags are being readable on later versions of Android, these should definitely count as being "readable".

All it needs is a KitKat implementation, which deals with `MifareUltralight` or `NfcA`.

One can fall-back without checking for the API level:

```
when (intent.action.toString()) {
    android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED -> {
        /* handle NDEF messages (business as usual). */
    }
    android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED -> {

        /* Check if NDEF format is present and read it. */
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)
        MifareUltralight mifare = MifareUltralight.get(tag)
        mifare.connect()
        ...
        mifare.close()

        /* When MifareUltralight is null, try NfcA: */
        // NfcA nfcA = NfcA.get(tag)
    }
    else -> {
        print("unknown intent action")
    }
}
```

`MifareUltralight` knows pages, `NfcA` is rather low-level and only knows `ByteArray` payloads.
Instead of suggesting different tags (which may trigger just the same `Intent`, which only would have to be handled accordingly), one could instead raise the `minApiLevel` and stop supporting KitKat altogether (the `Intent` still may be triggered for empty tags). I'd have NTAG216 and at least a physical API 22 device - to see which `Intent` it would *actually* trigger, but no time. One would need a physical API 19 device to properly reproduce this.

Comment: The `MifareUltralight` is a totally different Tag to the `MifareClassic` you seem to be confused and are talking about the wrong Tag Hardware., As a `MifareUltralight` is a Type 2 Tag and therefore always supported as it is part of the NFC Froum Specification.  Also `NdefFormatable` `TECH_DISCOVERED` would be identified before `TAG_DISCOVERED` if the card was capable of being formatted to store NDEF messages.